# Маршрутизация трафика OpenVPN через WireGuard VPN

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, wireguard

Имеется **OpenVPN Server**, для подключения к которому необходим статический адрес (в whitelist). Для получения статического адреса используется **WireGuard VPN**.

Клиент подключается к **WG**, получает статику, имеет доступ в интернет, затем подключается к **OVPN**.

Проблема заключается в том, что клиент не получает доступ к ресурсам находящимся за **OVPN**, а так же не имеет доступа в интернет после полной процедуры подключения.

Как нужно настроить маршрутизацию на **клиенте** и/или **WG сервере** (доступа к OVPN серверу нет), чтобы клиент имел IP-адрес **OVPN** и имел доступ к ресурсам за ним?